# How to upload file to AWS S3 using Camel aws-s3 producer?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, apache-camel

I'm trying to upload a jpg file to AWS S3 bucket with Camel's aws-s3 producer. Can I make this work with this approach and if yes how? Now I'm only getting an IOException and can't figure out what would be the next step. I know I could implement the upload using TransferManager from the aws-sdk but now I'm only interested in Camel's aws-s3 endpoint.

Here is my route with Camel 2.15.3:

```
public void configure() {
    from("file://src/data?fileName=file.jpg&noop=true&delay=15m")
    .setHeader(S3Constants.KEY,constant("CamelFile"))
    .to("aws-s3://<bucket-name>?region=eu-west-1&accessKey=<key>&secretKey=RAW(<secret>)");
}
```

and the exception I get from running that route:

```
com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to create HTTP entity: Stream Closed
at com.amazonaws.http.HttpRequestFactory.newBufferedHttpEntity(HttpRequestFactory.java:244)
at com.amazonaws.http.HttpRequestFactory.createHttpRequest(HttpRequestFactory.java:122)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:415)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:273)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3660)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1432)
at org.apache.camel.component.aws.s3.S3Producer.processSingleOp(S3Producer.java:209)
at org.apache.camel.component.aws.s3.S3Producer.process(S3Producer.java:71)
at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:129)
at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:448)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)
at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processExchange(GenericFileConsumer.java:439)
at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processBatch(GenericFileConsumer.java:211)
at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:175)
at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:174)
at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:101)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:246)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.RepeatableInputStream.read(RepeatableInputStream.java:167)
at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:73)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.MD5DigestCalculatingInputStream.read(MD5DigestCalculatingInputStream.java:88)
at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:73)
at com.amazonaws.event.ProgressInputStream.read(ProgressInputStream.java:151)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
at org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toByteArray(EntityUtils.java:136)
at org.apache.http.entity.BufferedHttpEntity.<init>(BufferedHttpEntity.java:63)
at com.amazonaws.http.HttpRequestFactory.newBufferedHttpEntity(HttpRequestFactory.java:242)
... 27 more
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did some digging and found one solution. Route works if you convert file contents to byte array before passing it to the aws-s3 endpoint like this:

```
from("file://src/data?fileName=file.jpg&noop=true&delay=15m")
    .convertBodyTo(byte[].class)
    .setHeader(S3Constants.CONTENT_LENGTH, simple("${in.header.CamelFileLength}"))
    .setHeader(S3Constants.KEY,simple("${in.header.CamelFileNameOnly}"))
    .to("aws-s3://{{awsS3BucketName}}"
                    + "?deleteAfterWrite=false&region=eu-west-1"
                    + "&accessKey={{awsAccessKey}}"
                    + "&secretKey=RAW({{awsAccessKeySecret}})")
    .log("done.");
}
```

There must also be S3Constants.CONTENT_LENGTH header value set to the file length in bytes.

The solution above reads whole file to memory so it's not ideal to every situation. However the code above is also the most simple way that I know of using aws-s3 producer endpoint. I'm still happy to hear about other (and better) solutions.

Comment: How to get the downloadable link from s3 after uploading

Comment: Camel S3 producer does not set link to the resource in output headers but S3 URLs are in the following format https://s3-<REGION>.amazonaws.com/<BUCKET_NAME>/<OBJECT_KEY> so you can build the link by yourself based on region, bucket name and object key.

Comment: @jnupponen - you mentioned you are using Camel 2.15.3. What is the maven dependency you are using? I can only see the dependency for Camel 3 on Maven Central - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-aws-s3

Comment: @adesai Camel 2.15.3 https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-aws/2.15.3 However that is really old version and I suggest using newest Camel dependencies as you have linked.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using camel xml dsl. The following operation will perform an upload of the file s3File.txt in the S3 bucket with based on the content the file src/empty.txt. I am using came 2.21.1

```
<!--upload file to AWS S3 -->
<setHeader headerName="CamelAwsS3Key">
 <exchangeProperty>s3File.txt</exchangeProperty>
</setHeader>
<setBody>
   <!--fileName with location to be uploaded -->
  <exchangeProperty>src/localfile.txt</exchangeProperty>
</setBody>
<convertBodyTo type="java.io.File"/>

 <!--upload the file to s3 pvc medicare leg2 outbound bucket-->
 <to uri="aws-s3:bucketName?amazonS3Client=#s3Client"/>
```